# Printing the messages having problem in SIM 900A to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I have added my Arduino code for reading messages from GSM SIM900A using Arduino. But the output is showing something different. Please help me.

```
#define SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE 256

char msg;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module
  delay(60000);
  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CREG=1");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGR=\"ALL\"");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CMGR=\"ALL\"");
  delay(1000);
  while ( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();  // removing serial buffer values
  Serial.println("AT+CMGR=1");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    msg = serial.read()
    Serial.print(msg);
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
+CMGR: "REC READ","+91xxxxxxxxxx","","16/07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Guys i found the issue. Serial.read() function reads only 62bytes. After i have update the serial buffer size in library file C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial.H ... It shows the messages which is stored in serial buffer.

Comment: Please note that you may want to check/handle the responses on these commands.

Comment: Please, accept your own answer to close this question.